# Node.js - Await for all the promises thrown inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm dealing with a loop in Node.js that performs two tasks for every iteration of a loop. To simplify, the code is summarized in:

1. Extract products metadata from a web page (blocking task).
2. Save all the products metadata to a database (asynchronous task).

The save operation (`2`) will perform about 800 operations in a database, and it doesn't need to block the main thread (I can still extracting products metadata from the web pages).

So, that being said, awaiting for the products to being saved doesn't have any sense. But if I throw the promises without awaiting for them, in the last iteration of the loop the Node.js process exits and all the pending operations are not finished.

Which is the best approach to solve this? Is it possible to achieve it without having a counter for finished promises or emitters? Thanks.

```
for (let shop of shops) {
  // 1
  const products = await extractProductsMetadata(shop);

  // 2
  await saveProductsMetadata(products);
}
```

Comment: You can either: 1) Make an array of promises where you store **all** the promises dealing with products and execute them all **after** the for loop, exiting the process only after all the promises are done (using Promise.all) 2) Redesign the process so that **another** node process/script takes care of executing all the queries.

Comment: `The save operation (2) will perform about 800 operations in a database, and it doesn't need to block the main thread (I can still extracting products metadata from the web pages).` can multiple save's be done at once?

Comment: Yes @JaromandaX , multiples save's can de done at once!

Comment: but `extractProductsMetadata` must be run one at a time, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's also correct @JaromandaX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are creating packs of data to treat. When we treat the data, we do all the get synchronously, and all the save asynchronously.

I have not handled the failure part, I let you add it to it. appropriate `try/catch` or function encapsulation will do it.

```
/**
 * Call the given functions that returns promises in a queue
 * options = context/args
 */
function promiseQueue(promisesFuncs, options = {}, _i = 0, _ret = []) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (_i >= promisesFuncs.length) {
      return resolve(_ret);
    }

    // Call one
    (promisesFuncs[_i]).apply(options.context || this, options.args || [])
      .then((ret: any) => promiseQueue(promisesFuncs, _i + 1, options, [
        ..._ret,

        ret,
      ]))
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);
  });
}

function async executePromiseAsPacks(arr, packSize, _i = 0) {
  const toExecute = arr.slice(_i * packSize, packSize);

  // Leave if we did execute all packs
  if (toExecute.length === 0) return true;

  // First we get all the data synchronously
  const products = await promiseQueue(toExecute.map(x => () => extractProductsMetadata(x)));

  // Then save the products asynchronously
  // We do not put await here so it's truly asynchronous
  Promise.all(toExecute.map((x, xi) => saveProductsMetadata(products[xi])));

  // Call next
  return executePromiseAsPacks(arr, packSize, _i + 1);
}

// Makes pack of data to treat (we extract synchronously and save asynchronously)
// Made to handle huge dataset
await executePromisesAsPacks(shops, 50);
```

Comment: @JonasWilms totally agree, it was just the time to edit it ;)

Comment: this code will "extract then save" each  `x` concurrently - I don't think OP wants mutliple extracts running concurrently (which this code WILL do) - see comments in question which verified this fact

Comment: @Elias garcia I've edited my code, please ask if something is not clear

Comment: I'm having a look at your code now, I've thought of doing something like this but I also though that it will be a 'more native' way of doing this, but I'm seeing that's not possible. I think I'll we go this way, thanks a lot for the example! :)

Comment: This would be reusable if you would move the task itself out of `executePromisesAsPack`

Answer (score 2):

Collect the promises in an array, then use `Promise.all` on it:

```
 const storePromises = [];

 for (let shop of shops) {
    const products = await extractProductsMetadata(shop); //(1)
    storePromises.push(saveProductsMetadata(products)); //(2)
 }

 await Promise.all(storePromises);
 // ... all done (3)
```

Through that (1) will run one after each other, (2) will run in parallel, and (3) will run afterwards.

For sure you can also run (1) and (2) in parallel:

```
  await Promise.all(shops.map(async shop => {
    const products = await extractProductsMetadata(shop); //(1)
    await saveProductsMetadata(products);
 }));
```

And if an error occured in one of the promises, you can handle that with a `try / catch` block, to make sure all other shops won't be affected:

```
 await Promise.all(shops.map(async shop => {
  try {
    const products = await extractProductsMetadata(shop); //(1)
    await saveProductsMetadata(products);
   } catch(error) {
     // handle it here
   }
 }));
```

> how to signal node to finish the process ?

You could manually call `process.exit(0);`, but that hides the real problem: NodeJS exits automatically if there is *no listener attached anymore*. That means that you should close all database connections / servers / etc. after the code above is done.

Comment: Will still stops in case of one Promise failure

Comment: It can be hundred of stores and thousands of products for each one. I don't think awaiting for 100.000 promises at the same will be a great idea... Especially working with database heavy operations.

Comment: @grégory I think by "throwing the promise" the OP talks about a "fire and forget" strategy and not about actually `throw`ing inside the promise.

Comment: @elias yes Indeed, this should actually be a database aggregation that the database can run on its own wothout NodeJS.

Comment: Also, this will never be storing anything in the database if a problem in the `extractProductsMetadata()` occurs.

Comment: @EliasGarcia - exactly the same case as in the original code, so, what's your point :p

Comment: @elias wait ... we are actually talking about rejected promises here?

Comment: Yes @JaromandaX , the code I have posted is wrong, I'm asking how to achieve concurrency there!

Comment: @JonasWilms no... what I'm trying to achieve is to store for each iteration of the loop, the products metadata of that iteration in the database. And how to signal node to finish the process when all of that promises have finished

Comment: @EliasGarcia - error handling and concurrency are not the same thing

Comment: Yes I know... Thanks for updating the answer! But the problem is that I need to save the current shop products metadata on each iteration... I can't wait fo finish all the shops to save all the products of all of the stores (so `Promise.all` is not an option). So I want to do that operations concurrently and await for all of them to finish to close the db connection.

Comment: Why is that not an option?

Comment: Because I can have 100k ops in database easily, it can runs out of memory also easily. Also I need to store the data for each shop in the iteration.

Comment: Then batch requests. "Also I need to store the data for each shop in the iteration" then do that?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for, to batch promises by shop and how to track all of them.